# What UID is used by MySQL when a query is made?

Tags: mysql, shell, permissions

I'm trying to read a file through MySQL's `load_file` command. But the result returned is Null and no error has occured in my query.

Since the file I'm trying to read is `www-data` protected, i'm wondering what my identity is in the server, if it isn't `www-data`.

It's pretty strange since I can use `load_file` to read `/etc/passwd` file.

Comment: MySQL queries should spawn a new thread under the same Linux username/usergroup that MySQL has.

Comment: What does `ls -l /etc/passwd` output?

Comment: It sounds like you are somewhat confused by how permissions work. "...s www-data protected" doesn't mean anything. The DBMS should not be running as www-data, and you should not be logging into the system as www-data. You might consider starting here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UID doesn't matter. The `LOAD_FILE` function will only read files that are world-readable. From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file):

> The file must be **readable by all** and its size less than `max_allowed_packet` bytes. If the `secure_file_priv` system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.

So you can't use this to read a file that's only readable by the `www-data` user. You can use it with `/etc/passwd` because anyone can read that file.

Comment: That's a clean answer and it made me understand my problem. Thanks.